# Flow types for react-native's Animated library

Tags: animation, react-native, flowtype

I am trying to use **react-native's Animated** library alongside **Flow**. Unfortunately, I get a bunch of Flow errors that I cannot resolve (see Screenshot).

In the example below I render a circle on the screen and want to make it move when it is being rendered using `Animated.spring`. Is there anything else I need to add to make react-native work with Flow?

Flow version: 0.54.0 / react-native version: 0.48.0

Currently, I am just ignoring Animated in `.flowconfig` :(

```
; Ignore Animated
.*/react-native/Libraries/Animated/**/.*
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe your specific problem is fixed in a more recent version of react-native. What might be useful to know is that you can annotate `position` with `AnimatedValueXY` importing one of the two

```
import type AnimatedValueXY from 'react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValueXY';
import type AnimatedValue from 'react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue';
```

It's kinda ugly but I didn't find a better alternative