# How to check type in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, flowtype

I have a problem, already solved it, but make me confuse about modules.

I tried to import an Animated in my component.

```
import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
```

and then, I tried to find Its type (flow), I found that answer in.
[Flow types for react-native's Animated library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040202/flow-types-for-react-natives-animated-library) (Thank you).

```
import type AnimatedValue from 'react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue';
```

The question is.
When I open Animated in `import { Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';`(right click, then I go to type definition with "Visual code"), Why it doesn't go to Its module, but to this path? (Library/Caches)
[image]
I tried to find out this file (index.d.ts) in "react-native" modules, but I cant find it. Why?

Then I try to read index.d.ts, to find out type for Animated.Value.

```
export namespace Animated {
    type AnimatedValue = Value;
    type AnimatedValueXY = ValueXY;
export class Value extends AnimatedWithChildren {
```

Horraay, I got Animated.Value is a class, and Its type is an AnimatedValue. Then as usual to find Its path, I right click, then I go to type definition with "Visual code", but I found nothing.

So, how can this `import type AnimatedValue from 'react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue` relate to `type AnimatedValue = Value;` in index.d.ts?

"react-native": "0.63.2",

Answer (score 1):

`index.d.ts` files are used to provide typescript type information about a module that's already written in JavaScript. This will allow you to use the javascript modules without the need to first convert them completely to `ts` without getting any type error on your code.

> Why it doesn't go to Its module, but to this path?

It's because when you install types for particular library using npm, they get installed under `node_modules/@types/<library-name>/` location as `index.d.ts` file. Therefore using VSCode's navigate to type definition feature takes you to this `index.d.ts` file instead of taking you within library.

> I tried to find out this file (index.d.ts) in "react-native" modules,
> but I cant find it. Why?

All `index.d.ts` files are stored at `node_modules/@types/<library-name>` not at `node_modules/<library-name>`. As a result you can't finid these files in corresponding modules.